# Where do I define index?

Tags: php

`index.php` contains links in this style:

```
<a href="index.php?id=1">1</a>
<a href="index.php?id=2">2</a>
```

and then a PHP passage in this style:

```
if ($_GET["id"] == "1") {}
elseif ($_GET["id"] == "2") {}
```

So when a link is clicked, the page is reloaded, and one of the if/elseif blocks is run.

However, when I load `index.php` the first time I get this error: **Undefined index: id**

I guess this means that `$_GET["id"]` needs to have a default value. But where do I put this default value in my code? If I give it, for example, the value `"0"` in the beginning of the script, the code blocks will never run, since the value keeps being reset on every reload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first check to see if it has been set:

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {

    if ($_GET["id"] == "1") {

    } elseif ($_GET["id"] == "2") {

    }

}
```

[isset](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a language construct which will not issue any errors if the variable isn't set.

[empty](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) also won't issue errors but also checks for a "non-empty" value.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any cost difference between the two functions if we don't mind if it is checking "non-empty" values or not?

Comment: Thanks @webbiedave. I appreciate the info about isset and empty not issuing errors. You're missing a ) on line 1, though. :)

Comment: Thanks, Johanna. I've fixed the missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

First, ignore the answers which advise you to set default value. That is not required and is atrocious design. Check if the value is present before checking it.

I would advise against using else/elseif chains. As your links increase, so does the ugliness of your code. Use a switch:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){

  switch($_GET['id']){
    case 1:
      // code
      break;
    case 2:
      // code
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Damien. Nice tips about not needing to set a default value and about the switch.

Comment: @aj: you edited my question for grammar, and changed 'value is' to 'value are'. Please don't edit people's questions unless you understand English yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to check if $_GET['id'] is empty, if so then set to be 0.

```
if(empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $_GET['id'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`if (!isset($_GET["id"]))
{
   $_GET["id"] = "0"
}`

Answer (score 1):

The first time you load a page, it won't have any query parameters.

You should wrap the conditions inside another condition that checks for the existence of `id`:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // you can use switch or keep the ifelseif chain
    switch ($_GET['id']) {
        case 1:
            // do stuff with 1
            break;

        case 2:
            // do stuff with 2
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

if ($id == "1") {}
} elseif ($id == "2") {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($_GET["id"] == "1") {}
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']==1){}
```